# Spring Data JPA query method 'Desc' not recognized

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have the following domain object:

```
public class Quizz {
    private Long id;
    private Date when;
    private Long userId;
}
```

I want to create a query method using Spring Data JPA that would give me the Quizz with the biggest id (latest inserted), something like this:

```
Quizz findTopOrderByIdDesc();
```

But it says `Cannot resolve property 'desc'`

Could you tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before OrderBy you have to place 'By':

```
Quizz findTopByOrderByIdDesc();
```

[Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).